# I can't post comments on first generation iPad

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface, comments

I have a first generation iPad, with OS 5.1.1, and sometimes look at MathOverflow on it, in the Safari web browser. Recently, it seems as though posting comments has stopped working. I type the comment into the text box OK, but then the "Add Comment" button is completely unresponsive. Otherwise MO still seems to work fine.

Does anybody know what's up? Or has anybody else suffered the same problem?

Probably it's not just MO, but math.SE is the only other site where I ever post comments, and I don't recall trying to do it there on my iPad recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry but we don't support [that version of Safari](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) anymore.

Comment: That list calls for a revision. Firefox 37 is old. Perhaps adding the sentence "or newer" will make it mathematically correct again. :-P

Comment: OK, thanks. Unfortunately I haven't found any other browser that's compatible with a first generation iPad that solves the problem. If anybody knows of one then I'd be very interested to hear of it.